# Ionic time picker not displaying instead displaying date picker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I followed the document from Ionic, below is code given to display the time picker.
But when clicked it's opening the data picket and no option to select time.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh-mm-A"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

What I'm missing please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ion-datetime display-format="h:mm A" picker-format="h:mm A" value="1990-02-19T07:43Z"></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: yeah it's working, but any idea why the above code doesn't work ?

Comment: You need to add picker-format to ion datetime picker

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-datetime placeholder="Select Time" displayFormat="hh:mm A"></ion-datetime>
```